# flutter why is this fired twice?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this simple code.
The method `getPrint` returns 'a', 'b', 'c' twice.
Total six String are returned.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
  List<String> li;

  Future<List<String>> getList() async {
    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  }

  void getPrint() {
    for (String l in li) {
      print(l);
    }
  }

  void _init() async {
    li = await getList();
    getPrint();
  }

  @override
    void initState() {
      _init();
      super.initState();
    }
```

Comment: I'm using same code and its display only one time a,b,c

Comment: I've run this several times both as simple dart files and in a flutter widget and I only get the print once every time.

Comment: really? In my case every time I tapped bottom navigation bar, print twice. Is this about bottom navigation perhaps then?

Comment: Can you show the actual widget you use? You're likely doing something wrong. I'd guess you're using FutureBuilder and call `init` from build

Comment: Sorry it was about bottom navigation bar I called setState to change background color of bottom navigation and that's the reason. Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shared shouldn't cause anything to be run twice. However, calling [`setState()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) as you've mentioned in the comments will cause for the entire screen to be rebuilt again, consequentially causing the methods inside `initState()` to be run again.